# LINQ ToArray() with conditional

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following dataset:

```
WharehouseId    Sku     OnHold      InStock 
===========================================
1               ABC-123     N           20
2               ABC-123     N           13
3               ABC-123     Y           4
4               ABC-123     N           18
```

I need to create an `int[]` array that returns the `InStock` items, but the value should be `0` if `OnHold` equals `'Y'`. So in the dataset above, the array result should be:

```
{ 20, 13, 0, 18 }
```

I am able to accomplish this by the following:

```
int[] inStockQty = new int[4];
int i = 0;

foreach (var item in query)
{
    inStockQty[i] = item.OnHold == 'N' ? item.InStock : 0;
    i++;
}
```

But I'm wondering if there is also a way to do this using LINQ's `ToArray()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can move the conditional into LINQ's `Select`, like this:

```
var inStockQty = query.Select(item => item.OnHold == 'N' ? item.InStock : 0).ToArray();
```